# WAF.IO how to start compile?

Tags: waf

my question my look silly but I'm complete yellow bird in programming. 
Have challenge to compile using waf.io. I went thru basic instructions https://waf.io/apidocs/tutorial.html?highlight=start. But there is missing basic information: where I should put all these commands?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61815901/4408275) answer answers your question, therefore please accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must put these commands in a file named `wscript`. This file should be in the directory where your other project files are.

Then you will use the `waf` command in the same directory to run it.

Look at the [waf book](https://waf.io/book/).